# how to insert two entities into TableView

Tags: java, tableview

is it possible to use one TableView of two objects?

For example, imagine I am creating an invoice. In this invoice appear "products" and "services", so I have two entities:

```
 @Entity
 public class Product
 @Entity
 public class Service
```

When I create my table i do this:

```
 @FXML
 private TableView<Producto> tablaFactura;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<Producto, String> columnReferencia;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<Producto, Servicio> columnDescripcion;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<Producto, Float> columnCantidad;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<Producto, Float> columnPrecioUnitario;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<Producto, Float> columnPrecioTotal;

 productoData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    productoData.add(producto);

    columnReferencia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, String>("codigo"));
    columnDescripcion.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, Servicio>("nombre"));
    columnCantidad.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, Float>("coste"));
    columnPrecioUnitario.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, Float>("pvp"));
    columnPrecioTotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, Float>("stock"));

    tablaFactura.setItems(productoData);
```

So my question is how to insert in "columnDescription" sometimes product values, and other times service values?